# Is there a way to export a game into a .EXE file?

Tags: construct-2

I finished my first game, I and I want to export it. But, I do not want to do one of the options that was given (Website, Chrome Web Store, Kongregate (might actualy do), and some others). Is there a way to create a .EXE file for my game? If so, how?

I am using the free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using Free edition, so the answer for you is `no`. You have to upgrade to at least Personal license (€99.99).

[Compare features](https://www.scirra.com/store/construct-2)

Comment: I was hoping that would not be the answer. I guess I should be putting the fact I am using the free version in my questions from now on.

Comment: @ShadowZ., that's the limitation of the free edition I'm afraid.. Along with forbidden commercial use and missing some of the important features.. It's a way to tease people into trying out your software and then pretty much force you into buying it. Not that I blame them... Either way, if you want to create games that are multiplatform and it's free even for commercial use, why not look into Unity5 that just came out? It's surely harder to learn and much more complex, but you have a fully featured IDE and an engine you can create practically any game you'd like with.

Comment: I tried Unity, but I think I am going to have to have more free time along with more patience for it. Thanks for the reccomendation though. I will probably have to think it through if I really want to buy it (Construct 2) or not.